# How to Open and Manipulate Images in Excel VBA Without Compromising Image Quality

Tags: excel, vba, image, ms-word

I have a task that involves working with several images stored in a folder, and I've been using Excel VBA for similar jobs. Specifically, I need to open each *.jpg image one by one and add today's date to the bottom right corner of each image. However, I want to ensure that the image quality remains uncompromised during this process.

Is there a method or approach that allows me to open and manipulate these images using VBA in Excel without negatively impacting the image quality? I'd appreciate any guidance or code examples that can help me achieve this image manipulation task while maintaining the highest possible image quality.

The macro I envision should perform the following steps:

1. Open the image.
2. Add today's date to it.
3. Save the modified image in the same folder with additional text or overwrite the existing image if applicable.

```
Sub LoopThroughFoldersAndFiles()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Folder As Object
    Dim Subfolder As Object
    Dim File As Object
    
    FolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
        
    For Each Subfolder In Folder.SubFolders
        Debug.Print Subfolder; ":"
        For Each File In Subfolder.Files
            Debug.Print File.Name ' Print the file name in the Immediate Window
        Next File
    Next Subfolder

End Sub
```

Comment: Excel and Word are poor choices for this, because their object models have few tools for working with images. Consider automating PowerPoint to do this instead. The gold standard for this type of work is Adobe Photoshop. It has Actions, which are like simple macros to automate operations like yours. The image quality is the best you can get. https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/automate-a-process/m-p/10052201

Comment: If you really need to use Excel, you could always insert the image inside a sheet, add a textbox on top of it and then use the [copy range as picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmmnQ.png) feature to create the image you need. Then you can use the technique like [this one](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-extract-all-images-into-a-folder.1141971/) to export the images inside the workbook back into files.